# Get the coordinates of any point clicked on a Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a fixed size `<div>` in which I am plotting a Google map by center coordinates (22.308259, 73.180293).

When I click anywhere on the map I get an alert with the coordinates I specified as the center coordinates

Following is the script I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.308259, 73.180293),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            alert("Latitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "\r\nLongitude: " + e.latLng.lng());
        });
    }
</script>
```

I want wherever I click on the map I get the coordinates of the point clicked on the map and not the center coordinates which I am getting so far. What needs to change with my code?

Comment: The [posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/fgt7zyk5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function setupListener(map, name) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, name, function(e) {
            if (name == "click") {
                alert(e.latLng.lat().toFixed(6));
            }
        });
      }
```

Couldn't find your bug but this works. Hope its helpful.